# Differentiating hyperbolic functions.

Tags: derivatives, hyperbolic-functions

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}$Can anyhow me how to differentiate the following? I already tried using the product rule, but I can't quiet seem to succeed.

1. $\sech^{2} x$.
2. $2\bigl(\cosh(2x) - 2\bigr) \sech^{4}(x)$.

Thanks a million!

Comment: How does product rule not suceed ? And what about chain rule?

Comment: can you show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fist you can use chain rule, noting that:
$$
y=\mbox{sech}^2x = (\cosh x)^{-2}
$$
so you have:
$$
y'=-2 (\cosh x)^{-3}\sinh x = -2 \tanh x \mbox{  sech}^2x
$$
For the second use product rule and chain rule or, better, note that :
$$
\cosh (2x)=\cosh^2 x+\sinh^2 x
$$
so you can semplify.

Comment: what about next one though?